# How do I make an object change direction on tap?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm very new to Lua. This is what I tried:

```
local function tapListener( event )

-- Code executed when the button is tapped
if crate.gravityScale == 1 then crate.gravityScale=-1
if crate.gravityScale == -1 then crate.gravityScale=1
-- "event.target" is the tapped object
return true
end

local myButton = display.newRect( 540, 960, 1080, 1920 )
myButton:setFillColor( 0, 0.01 )
myButton:addEventListener( "tap", tapListener )
-- Add a "tap" listener to the object
```

What is the correct way to do this? I can't really understand how to do it with just API reference.

.......

Edit 8/19/17:
I didn't like how it moved with gravity so I changed it to setLinearVelocity but now it won't change direction on tap. Here's what I tried:

```
speed = 400

-- make a crate (off-screen), position it, and rotate slightly
local crate = display.newImageRect( "crate.png", 90, 90 )
crate.x, crate.y = 540, 1750
crate.rotation = 0
physics.addBody( crate, "dyanamic" )
crate:setLinearVelocity(speed, 0)

local function tapListener( event )

speed = speed == 400 and -400 or 400
return true
end

local myButton = display.newRect( 540, 960, 1080, 1920 )
myButton:setFillColor( 0, 0.01 )
myButton:addEventListener( "tap", tapListener )
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I'm also new to stackoverflow

Comment: Missing `end` keyword. I'm not sure you use two `if` statements or nested `if` statement. Try `crate.gravityScale = crate.gravityScale == 1 and -1 or 1` instead of `if` statements.

Comment: @lhf So what if it's not plain Lua? It's Lua and that's enough, if you don't know the answer just check other questions.

Comment: @ldurniat Thanks that worked.